# Linking two data tables by multiple columns in Spotfire

Tags: spotfire

I have two tables that I've loaded into spotfire. In these tables, 3 of the column names match but don't necessarily contain the same content.

For example:

Data Table 1 contains data in every column.

```
Name Feature-1 Feature-2 Feature-3
 A      AB        AC        BC
```

Data Table 2 contains the same column names, but 2/3 matching columns will be empty!

```
Name Feature-1 Feature-2 Feature-3
 A1      AB       NaN       NaN
 A2      NaN      AC        NaN
 A3      NaN      NaN       BC
```

I can successfully link the two data tables with a single column, but it seems like when I add relations for 3 columns ALL of those columns must match (column1 & column2 & column3).

Is there a way to specify I want to have any of those columns match (column1 or column2 or column3)?

Answer (score 0):

if the columns in table2 are such that only one of them is ever populated, you can calculate a column **[Features-merged]** as **Concatenate(Feature-1,Feature-2,Feature-3)** and use that for your relationship match